# Compute Forecast Error Variance Decomposition for variables outside the Vector Autoregression

Tags: vector-autoregression, variance-decomposition

I am replicating the paper of Ang and Piazzesi (2003) in the Journal of Monetary Economics (link: [here](http://web.stanford.edu/~piazzesi/AP.pdf)) where they estimate a Vector Autoregression for both unobservable factors and observable macroeconomic variables. Eventually, what they are interested in is explaining the movements of bond yields. For this, they use a no-arbitrage term structure model that links bond yields to economic factors that are "priced", i.e. that matter for the pricing of yields.

My problem arises in Appendix D when I need to calculate the Variance decompositions of *yields*. This refers to Table 9.

My question is the following: **How do I compute the Forecast Error Variance Decomposition of variables not included in the VAR, but for which I know the relation to variables included in the VAR?**

What I know so far:

- Yields are affected by fundamental shocks *through* unobservable and macroeconomic variables.
- given the feedback matrix of the VAR and the variance-covariance matrix, I can calculate the Impulse Response Functions of the variables included in the VAR to all the fundamental shocks in the VAR.
- given the loadings of unobservable factors onto the yields, I can calculate the Impulse Response Functions of yields of any maturity.
- In my research, macroeconomic variables do not directly affect yields, but can directly affect the unobservable factors. Only the unobservable factors are related to yields through no-arbitrage coefficients.
- I know how Forecast Error Variance Decomposition is linked to Impulse Response Functions. My doubts is how to handle the variance-covariance matrix for the unobservable and macro variables that should somehow be linked to variance-covariance of yields.

(See the graph below.)

Thank you very much for your answer.

[image]

Comment: Did you figure it out? We are working on that as well. Right now we are just using the Multipliers for macro and yield factors combined. So that the P_i are 5by5 matrices. And multiplying this to the factor loading coefficient,(B).